# wordpress prevent multiple shortcodes

Tags: plugins, shortcode

I created a wordpress plugin and I added shortcode feature to it. but i want to execute only one shortcode and prevent applying of multiple shortcodes if the administrator did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the shortcode during the first call.

```
add_shortcode( 'foo', 'foo_shortcode_handler' );

function foo_shortcode_handler()
{
    remove_shortcode( 'foo' );
    return 'bar';
}
```